# Swift3: value of type '(Any)-> ()' has no member 'setTitle'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to login and I'm doing tests right now and I'm trying when the log is correct I changed the title of the button but I get this error: value of type '(Any) -> ()' has no member ' SetTitle '. Then I leave you the code and a screenshot.

I need help because I'm blocked and I can not continue. All help will be appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

And this is my code

```
import UIKit

class LogViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var _username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var _password: UITextField!

    @IBAction func _login_button(_ sender: Any) {
        let username = _username.text
        let password = _password.text

        if(username == "" || password == "")
        {
            return
        }

        DoLogin(username!, password!)
    }



    func DoLogin(_ user:String, _ psw:String)
    {

        let url = URL(string: "http://localhost/bill/userLogin.php")
        let session = URLSession.shared

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        let paramToSend = "username=" + user + "&password=" + psw
        request.httpBody = paramToSend.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
                (data, response, error) in
            guard let _:Data = data else
            {
                return
            }

            let json:Any?
            do
            {
                json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
            }
            catch
            {
                return
            }

            guard let server_response = json as? NSDictionary else
            {
            return
            }

            if let data_block = server_response["data"] as? NSDictionary
            {
                if let session_data = data_block["session"] as? String
                {
                    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
                    preferences.set(session_data, forKey: "session")

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        execute:self.LoginDone()
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }

    func LoginDone()
    {
        _username.isEnabled = false
        _password.isEnabled = false
        _login_button.setTitle("Logout", for: .normal)
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: _login_button is IBAction not IBOutlet  of the button

Comment: `_login_button` is function not the button outlet, if you have declare outlet with same name then change either button name or function will solve your error

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll change the function and it will work. Thanks guys

Comment: @amr07 accept the answer. if it was helpful

Comment: Tell me how I accept it, since I am new to this forum: D

Comment: Consider to conform to the Swift (camelCased) naming convention. This is not javascript or PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have issue that is connected with _login_button because it is  @IBAction not @IBOutlet.

For solving of this issue drag outlet from storyboard and connect it with proper file.

And than set property of the button.

Example.

```
@IBOutlet weak var _login_button_outlet: UIButton!

func LoginDone()
{
    _username.isEnabled = false
    _password.isEnabled = false
    _login_button_outlet.setTitle("Logout", for: .normal)
}
```

Comment: @amr07 you are always welocme

Answer (score 0):

hi you trying to set the title to the _login_button which not the button its the @IBAction method so for setting the title you have to create @IBOutlet weak var _login_button: UIButton!.